# How can I sort the multi filter combobox in Kendo Grid mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to sort alphabetically  string values inside the multi filter combobox in Kendo Grid to filter. Now it shows randomly there is no any order in  mvc. Here is the code

```
columns.Bound(c => c.EmpName).Title("Employee Name")
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
.Multi(true)
```